Variable-Size Matrix
How can I let Mathematica tell me that trace(Identity matrix)=n for n by n identity matrix? It's easy for human but what would a Mathematica code be?
A harder task: How can I let Mathematica tell me that Exp[I] is also an n by n diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries equal to Exp[1]?
(I simplified my actual question so that humans already know the answer. My actual matrix M is an (2n+1) by (2n+1) tridiagonal matrix with each entry one. I want the [[n,n]] matrix entry of matrix M^n, so that I will then compute the same entry of Exp[M])
Related: How to define and compute various properties of a variable size matrix. But the problem is not resolved there.

For finite dimensions, nmax = 20; And @@ Table[MatrixExp[ IdentityMatrix[n]] == E*IdentityMatrix[n], {n, 1, nmax}]

Thanks! It would be great if Mathematica has the symbolic power for any-size matrices though, that is, return an answer in terms of nmax. I am not sure if Mathematica has some of these features for operators or tensors.

FullSimplify[MatrixExp[IdentityMatrix[n]]] doesn't really give me E*IdentityMatrix[n]

As indicated in my other comment, n must be a finite dimension, i.e., a positive integer.

I understand. But even if I put Assuming[{n \[Element] PositiveIntegers},   FullSimplify[MatrixExp[IdentityMatrix[n]]]], the result is not E*IdentityMatrix[n]. Are you suggesting that it is impossible for Mathematica to give an answer in terms of n?

I do not know of any way to do it symbolically.

In version 14.1 SymbolicIdentityArray is introduced as an EXPERIMENTAL function, but Tr cannot handle it for now. Perhaps next version?

So they can in principle do it? Wow, that will help on a lot of tridiagonal matrix problems in physics. It is kinda a huge advancement if there were no other way before. @xzczd

Yeah, though experimental, those functions in 14.1 for symbolic arrays are a big step forward and can already do a lot of interesting things. For more info check https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolicArrays.html

symbolic identity matrices are in V 14.2, see demo by Wolfram here starting at around 9.00  https://i.sstatic.net/9QPnDYAK.png  He said V 14.2 will be released "soon". My guess by Xmass time?
